# How to make download button in RShiny works so that it can download output displayed?

Tags: shiny

The system is an Audit Sample Selection System in which I used RStudio to develop the system. The system behaves as follows:

1. User upload Excel file or PDF file.
2. User need to choose between two radiobuttons, one is 'Low Risk' and another one is 'High Risk'.
3. The user click on 'Submit' button.
4. The system automatically selects certain number of audit samples depending on the number of rows of the table in the file.
5. The number of audit samples selected is different between 'Low Risk' and 'High Risk'.
6. The system displays the selected audit samples.
7. The user can download the selected audit samples displayed.

   ```
   library(shiny)
   library(xlsx)
   library(xlsxjars)
   library(rJava)
   library(pdftools)
   library(tabulizer)

   ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Audit Sample Selection System"),
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     fileInput("file1", "Choose file", accept = c(".xlsx", ".pdf")),
     radioButtons("select", "Level of Risk", choices=list("Low Risk" = "low","High Risk" = "high")),
     actionButton("submit", "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
    tableOutput("contents"),
    downloadButton("download", "Download")
    )
   )
   )

   server <- function(input, output){

   mydf <- eventReactive(input$submit, {

   # check for required values (for truthfulness)/ensure the values are available 
   req(input$select)
   req(input$file1)

   inFile <- input$file1

   if (grepl("*.xlsx",inFile[1]) == TRUE){
    file.rename(inFile$datapath, paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep = ""))          
    wb <- read.xlsx(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep = ""), 1)

    nrow(wb) -> rows
    if (input$select == "low") {
    # sample for low risk (xlsx)
    if (rows == 1) {
     outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 1), ]
    } else 
     if (rows >= 2 & rows <= 4) {
       outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 1), ]
     } else 
       if (rows >= 5 & rows <= 12) {
         outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 2), ]
       } else 
         if (rows >= 13 & rows <= 52) {
           outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 5), ]
         } else
           if (rows >= 53 & rows <= 365) {
             outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 15), ]
           } else
             if (rows > 365) {
               outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 25), ]
             }
    } else {
   # sample for high risk (xlsx)
   if (rows == 1) {
     outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 1), ]
   } else 
     if (rows >= 2 & rows <= 4) {
       outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 2), ]
     } else 
       if (rows >= 5 & rows <= 12) {
         outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 3), ]
       } else 
         if (rows >= 13 & rows <= 52) {
           outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 8), ]
         } else
           if (rows >= 53 & rows <= 365) {
             outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 25), ]
           } else
             if (rows > 365) {
               outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 40), ]
             } 
    }
    } else if (grepl("*.pdf",inFile[1]) == TRUE) {
       outtable <- extract_tables(inFile$datapath)
       outtable[[1]] <- outtable[[1]][-c(1,1),] # Remove header from the table on the first page
       df <- do.call(rbind, outtable) # Turn matrix into data frame
       nrow(df) -> rows
       if (input$select == "low") {
       # sample for low risk (pdf)
   if (rows == 1) {
     outdf <- df[sample(rows, 1), ]
   } else 
     if (rows >= 2 & rows <= 4) {
       outdf <- df[sample(rows, 1), ]
     } else 
       if (rows >= 5 & rows <= 12) {
         outdf <- df[sample(rows, 2), ]
       } else 
         if (rows >= 13 & rows <= 52) {
           outdf <- df[sample(rows, 5), ]
         } else
           if (rows >= 53 & rows <= 365) {
             outdf <- df[sample(rows, 15), ]
           } else
             if (rows > 365) {
               outdf <- df[sample(rows, 25), ]
             } 
        } else {
        # sample for high risk (pdf)
   if (rows == 1) {
     outdf <- df[sample(rows, 1), ]
   } else 
     if (rows >= 2 & rows <= 4) {
       outdf <- df[sample(rows, 2), ]
     } else 
       if (rows >= 5 & rows <= 12) {
         outdf <- df[sample(rows, 3), ]
       } else 
         if (rows >= 13 & rows <= 52) {
           outdf <- df[sample(rows, 8), ]
         } else
           if (rows >= 53 & rows <= 365) {
             outdf <- df[sample(rows, 25), ]
           } else
             if (rows > 365) {
               outdf <- df[sample(rows, 40), ]
             }
        }
      } else {
       NULL
      }
      })

      output$contents <- renderTable({
      mydf()
      })
     }

     shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
   ```

The problem is I do not know how to make the download button to work so that when the user click on the 'Download' button, the selected audit samples displayed will be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a download button, you could use the `DT` package to render a nice table and its "buttons" extension which allows to download the table.

```
library(DT)
# in server:
output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
  datatable(mydf(), 
            extensions = 'Buttons', 
            options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = 'excel'))
})
# in ui:
DT::dataTableOutput("contents")
```

See https://rstudio.github.io/DT/003-tabletools-buttons.html for more info on the "buttons" extension.